# trying to get value from a dict with integer key

Tags: python, list, dictionary, hashmap, mapping

I am working with a dict which is structured like this inside a function:

```
listOfInformation = [{123456789: {'PokemonId': '123456789', 'PokemonName': 'Pikachu', 'PokemonAttack': 'thunderbolt'}}]
```

In that function, I'm passing an integer as an argument (pokemon_id) and then trying to test if the key-value pair exists like this:

```
listOfInformation(pokemon_id)
```

But I am getting an error of IndexError, list index out of range. I can't figure out why would I get this error. how can I fix this?

I should be getting back the whole value of this:

```
{'PokemonId': '123456789', 'PokemonName': 'Pikachu', 'PokemonAttack': 'thunderbolt'}
```

Comment: You have a nested dictionary inside of a **list**. You need to get the dictionary of interest from the list first, and then work from there,

Comment: That's a list of dicts. Your example `listOfInformation(pokemon_id)` would return "list not callable". Did you mean `listOfInformation[pokemon_id]`?

Comment: Did you intend for all of the pokemon's to be in that dict? Then the outer list is the problem. What would it look like if there where two pokemons in the collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data structure appears to be a list containing one element, which is a dictionary.  If so, you should be using:

```py
listOfInformation = [{123456789: {'PokemonId': '123456789', 'PokemonName': 'Pikachu', 'PokemonAttack': 'thunderbolt'}}]
if 123456789 in listOfInformation[0]:
    print(listOfInformation[0][123456789])
```

The above prints:

```
{'PokemonId': '123456789', 'PokemonAttack': 'thunderbolt', 'PokemonName': 'Pikachu'}
```